# How do i change the trained model location for yolov8 model in colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

This is the command for training the model in colab

```
!yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolov8s.pt data=coco.yaml epochs=10 imgsz=640
```

i want to change the model's save location from /runs/exp to /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov8,how do i do that

I tried --weights parameters and some others but didnt work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use project=***name of folder*** where you want to save your results; i.e., in your case, `project=/content/drive/MyDrive/yolov8`.

In this way, a train folder will be created in your yolov8 folder and the results will be saved their. If you want to change the name "train" you can mention that as name=***folder name***

You can read more about these parameters here: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/yolo/cfg/default.yaml

Comment: corrected the link.